# how to scroll in summernote flutter

Tags: flutter, summernote

I'm using the summernote text editor but I don't know how to scroll in the summernote text editor.
This is my code:

```
FlutterSummernote(
  widthImage: '40%',
  hasAttachment: true,
  hint: "Your text here...",
  key: _keyWhatToDo,
  height: 450,
  customToolbar: """
    [
      ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline']],
      ['font', ['strikethrough']],
      ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
      ['color', ['color']],
      ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
    ]"""
),
```

please let me know if anything wrong or give me some advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated: As you requested, `FlutterSummernote` combined with `SingleChildScrollView`.

It's working as expected. I don't know which issue you've been facing. Try to write the below-mentioned code into your main.dart file & check the result.

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import "package:flutter_summernote/flutter_summernote.dart";

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Flutter Demo",
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final GlobalKey<FlutterSummernoteState> _keyWhatToDo = GlobalKey();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _keyWhatToDo.currentState?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(height: 200, color: Colors.blue),
              Container(height: 200, color: Colors.pink),
              FlutterSummernote(
                widthImage: "40%",
                hasAttachment: true,
                hint: "Your text here...",
                key: _keyWhatToDo,
                height: 450,
                customToolbar: """
              [
                ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline']],
                ['font', ['strikethrough']],
                ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
                ['color', ['color']],
                ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
              ]""",
              ),
              Container(height: 200, color: Colors.orange),
              Container(height: 200, color: Colors.green),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Here is the problem, the summernote text cannot be scrolled. is there any solution?

Comment: So, we can do one thing. Based on the keyboard's appearance, we can ON or OFF scroll. And that thing is patchy, but it is working. I just achieved that.

Comment: physics: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom == 0
              ? const ScrollPhysics()
              : const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),

Set this property in SingleChildScrollView.

Comment: Upvoting & accepting the answer is highly appreciated. Please consider it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's working as expected. I don't know which issue you've been facing.
Try to write the below-mentioned code into your `main.dart` file & check the result.

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import "package:flutter_summernote/flutter_summernote.dart";

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Flutter Demo",
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final GlobalKey<FlutterSummernoteState> _keyWhatToDo = GlobalKey();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _keyWhatToDo.currentState?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            // Your widgets
            FlutterSummernote(
              widthImage: "40%",
              hasAttachment: true,
              hint: "Your text here...",
              key: _keyWhatToDo,
              height: 450,
              customToolbar: """
              [
                ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline']],
                ['font', ['strikethrough']],
                ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
                ['color', ['color']],
                ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
              ]""",
            ),
            // Your widgets
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: there seems to be a problem if combined with SingleChildScrollView. but thanks for the help

Comment: Do you want that? If you say, I can try it with SingleChildScrollView.

Comment: sure, can u help me?

Comment: I deliver a new answer. Check it out.